# Angular 7 Get parms of child route

Tags: angular, angular6, angular7, router

Getting `params.get("id")`  only from correspond page component,  Coudnt access params id from other individual components (headerComponent)

```
//Its worked only correspond component only 

 this.activatedRoute.paramMap.subscribe( params => {
      this.projectName  = params.get("id");
      console.log( this.projectName );
    })



//Tried with these codes

    console.log( this.activatedRoute.children[0].children[1].params['id'] )
    this.activatedRoute.firstChild.params.subscribe(params => {
      let id = +params['id'];
      console.log(id)
    });
console error (line number is where i tried to console in page)
at HeaderComponent.push../src/app/common/header/header.component.ts.HeaderComponent.ngOnInit
```

**Structure**

```
<app-header></app-header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>

app.module.ts
app-routing.module.ts
common/
--header.component.ts
projects/
  component-folder
--projects.module.ts
--projects-routing.module.ts (child route)
```

And alternate, is it possible to access params from directives?

Answer (score 1):

You want to access param id from other individual components (headerComponent), Use `Router NavigationEnd` event, Hope it will give.

Comment: Can I get an example code of how to use this syntax

Comment: `import { Router,NavigationEnd  } from '@angular/router';

constructor(private route : Router){
 route.events.subscribe( e => {
  if(e instanceof NavigationEnd){
   // code ...
  }
 });
}`

Comment: Perfect, got url , but How can I get exact param.id ?

Comment: you can use one more class `ActivatedRoute` or `ActivatedRouteSnapshot`. and use `this._activatedRoute.params.subscribe( param => { // code .... });`